# Lock screen in portrait on configuration change

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I have a simple activity with a boolean. I want it to change from portrait to landscape if and only if that boolean is false (only if the screen changes orientation, of course).

I tried this:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged((listening) ? getListeningConfiguration(newConfig)
                : newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.medidor);
        preconfigureLayout();
    }

    public Configuration getListeningConfiguration(final Configuration c) {
        c.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        return c;
    }
```

But it simply won't work.

How can I force an activity to remain in portrait state unless I tell it it can change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call this to keep it in portrait:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

That *should* do the trick

Comment: In your `onCreate()`, and every time you change your mind about locking the orientation

Answer (score 5):

In manifest file in activity tag add

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

That will keep your activity in portrait mode. then use your code for orientation change.

Comment: He wants to do it programmatically

Comment: Yup, doing it statically won't solve my needs. Anyway, thank you for the info.